# Avoid creating new resource if it exists using serverless

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I have a shared resource between many Cloud Stacks, and I want `Serverless` to ignore creating the resource if it exists, I found this configuration written in `YAML` to create a new resource, but I wanted it to ignore creating it if it exists, Is there a way to do it?

```
# you can add CloudFormation resource templates here
resources:
    Resources:
       NewResource:
          Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
          Properties:
             BucketName: saif-bucket
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an article about sharing resources between different serverless projects, and it seems that we can just define the resource as `S3SharedBucketArtifacts` instead of `NewResource` and that will do the trick.

Code will be :

```
# you can add CloudFormation resource templates here
resources:
    Resources:
       S3SharedBucketArtifacts:
          Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
          Properties:
             BucketName: saif-bucket
```

Reference: 
[How to reuse an AWS S3 bucket for multiple Serverless Framework](https://medium.com/serverlessguru/how-to-reuse-an-aws-s3-bucket-for-multiple-serverless-framework-deployments-d1673d3d8259)